# Remove all <p> tags inside of <li> tags with HTML Purifier

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

As the title says I need to remove all `<p>` tags inside of `<li>` tags with HTML Purifier.

My input is like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>111</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>222</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>333</p>
```

and it should be cleaned liked this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>111</li>
    <li>222</li>
</ul>
<p>333</p>
```

I can't get it to work no matter what I try. I can see a similar thing working [in the example](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=colgroup%3A%0D%0Ath%3A%0D%0Atd%3A%0D%0Aiframe%3Asrc%0D%0A&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=1&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=1&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Cb%3EInline%20%3Cdel%3Econtext%20%3Cdiv%3ENo%20block%20allowed%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdel%3E%3C%2Fb%3E&submit=Submit). It does work there as inline tag does not allow block children. But `<li>` is block and does allow `<p>` by specification. But I still need it out. Please help)

Comment: tag `p` inside tag `li` is valid, so you can use javascript.

Comment: This is a server script to be run against the data from database, so js seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I found Awesome PHP function for skip tags

```
<?php 
$tags="<ul>
    <li>
        <p>111</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>222</p>
    </li>
</ul>";
echo strip_tags($tags, ["li","ul"]);
?>
```

`strip_tags` takes two parameter one is html string and other is acceptable tags. it will automatically remove tags which are not defined in acceptable list.

the output string it generates:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        111
    </li>
    <li>
        222
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. My example is a bit simplified. In fact, I have `<p>` tags elsewhere, not only inside `<li>`. And those should not be removed. I think I can't achieve that with `strip_tags`, can I?

Comment: Strip_tags can cause problems if the string has an incorrect syntax such as no closing tags. It will end up deleting everything after the opening tag in the string.

Comment: Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using PHP's DOMDocument after purifying in with HTML Purifier - https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Loop through all paragraph `<p>` elements and if their direct parent is list item `<li>`, set `li`'s `textContent` to `p`'s `textContent`.
Something like that:

```
$html = '<ul>
    <li>
        <p>111</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>222</p>
    </li>
</ul>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // See https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php#119767
$paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$paragraphsLength = $paragraphs->length;

for ($i = 0; $i < $paragraphsLength; $i++) {
    $p = $paragraphs->item(0); // See https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#99716
    if ($p->parentNode->tagName === 'li') {
        $p->parentNode->textContent = $p->textContent;
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Update:

> My example is a bit simplified. In fact, I have `<p>` tags elsewhere, not only inside `<li>`

In the case that your HTML is much bigger. Naively looping through all paragraphs might not be the most performant way and you should look into [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).
For example:

```
/*...*/
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$paragraphs = $xpath->query('//li/p');
/*...*/
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. As far as I know DOMDocument likes to have a well-formed input. And HTML Purifier will probably provide it. Will try this if I can't find a HTML Purifier only solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "strip_tags()"
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

but it will remove  all tags ,but you can keep allowed ones

or `str_replace`:

```
$result = str_replace(array("<p>","</p>"), array('', ''), $str);
```

Comment: I am sure I could get away with `preg_replace`, `str_replace` is probably not exactly usable here. But I would like to stay within HTML Purifier as I use it for inline styles removal and other minor things.

Comment: Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.